# Toolbar accessory added to UITextView as a UIViewRepresentable only displays after first launch of iMessage extension application

Tags: swiftui, uitextview, toolbar, imessage-extension, uiviewrepresentable

Would like to have the toolbar show all the time.

Any help is greatly appreciated as this is a real drag for the user experience.

I've added a toolbar to the keyboard for the TextView as shown below.
However the toolbar only shows after the app has run once.  Meaning the toolbar does not show the first time the app is run. the app works every time after the initial load.

This is on IOS 14.3, Xcode 12.3, Swift 5, iMessage extension app.  Fails on simulator or real device.

```
struct CustomTextEditor: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    private var returnType: UIReturnKeyType
    private var keyType: UIKeyboardType
    private var displayDoneBar: Bool
    private var commitHandler: (()->Void)?
    
    init(text: Binding<String>,
         returnType: UIReturnKeyType = .done,
         keyboardType: UIKeyboardType,
         displayDoneBar: Bool,
         onCommit: (()->Void)?) {
        self._text = text
        self.returnType = returnType
        self.keyType = keyboardType
        self.displayDoneBar = displayDoneBar
        self.commitHandler = onCommit
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        
        textView.keyboardType = keyType
        textView.returnKeyType = returnType
        textView.backgroundColor = .clear
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .regular)
        textView.isEditable = true
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        if self.displayDoneBar {
            let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace,
                                                target: self,
                                                action: nil)
            let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Close Keyboard",
                                             style: .done,
                                             target: self,
                                             action: #selector(textView.doneButtonPressed(button:)))
            
           let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 50))
            toolBar.items = [flexibleSpace, doneButton, flexibleSpace]
            toolBar.setItems([flexibleSpace, doneButton, flexibleSpace], animated: true)
            toolBar.sizeToFit()
            textView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
            textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
            textView.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

        }

        return textView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ textView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        textView.text = text
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {

        var parent: CustomTextEditor

        init(_ textView: CustomTextEditor) {
            self.parent = textView
        }

        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            self.parent.$text.wrappedValue = textView.text
        }
        func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
            self.parent.$text.wrappedValue = textView.text
            parent.commitHandler?()
        }
    }
    
}

extension UITextView {
    @objc func doneButtonPressed(button:UIBarButtonItem) -> Void {
       self.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

This is how it's called...

```
import SwiftUI
    
final class ContentViewHostController: UIHostingController<ContentView> {
        weak var myWindow: UIWindow?
        init() {
            super.init(rootView: ContentView())
        }
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: coder, rootView: ContentView())
        }
    }
let kTextColor = Color(hex: "3E484F")
let kOverlayRadius: CGFloat = 10
let kOverlayWidth: CGFloat = 2
let kOverlayColor = kTextColor
        
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = ""
            
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            CustomTextEditor(text: $text, returnType: .default, keyboardType: .default, displayDoneBar: true, onCommit: nil)
                        .foregroundColor(kTextColor)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: kOverlayRadius)
                                .stroke(kOverlayColor, lineWidth: kOverlayWidth)
                        )
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
        
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

From MessagesViewController...

override func willBecomeActive(with conversation: MSConversation) {
    let childViewCtrl = ContentViewHostController()
    childViewCtrl.view.layoutIfNeeded() // avoids snapshot warning?
        
    if let window = self.view.window {
        childViewCtrl.myWindow = window
        window.rootViewController = childViewCtrl
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean at first time? If I open the app, it is not calling firstResponder. Hence no keyboard being showed and that's why no toolbar is there. You want to immediately start editing?

Comment: I install & launch the app first time, the view that contains the TextView is presented.  The user taps on the TextView to add data.  The keyboard has NO toolbar.  Quit the app, launch again (or any subsequent run), tap the TextView, and the toolbar IS present.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said this is an iMessage app. I just made a standalone non-iMessage test app that launches the toolbar fine. So this is most likely a problem w/ iMessage and the textview.  I've added the slimmed down version.

Comment: update: I've got the slimmed down version working.  So, that means something in the other parts of the view (which I deleted here for brevity & security), is causing the issue.  If anyone else is seeing this behavior I'd appreciate knowing what could cause it?

Comment: Workaround: 
I gutted the iMessage app's views to only have what is displayed above.  The problem still persists.

It appears that the problem is in the MessagesViewController somewhere.  The workaround is to give the user a message on application install (first launch) to restart iMessage, and using UserDefaults to determine whether this is the first launch or not, continue in the application or display this message.

My code does not change from intial run to subsequent runs.  Only the environment does.  It appears to be a bug in iMessage (I hate saying that w/ out knowing for sure).